# Is my husband's ex-wife haram to him in the sense of being alone with him without me being present?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, non-mahram

I got married earlier this year to a man who has been divorced now going on 12 years. I would like to know if his ex wife is haram to him in the sense of being alone with him without me being present?

I have always dealt with my feelings of uncomfortability because of the children they have together and not wanting to cause hassles but i do not feel comfortable with this set up. I am trying to understand what is acceptable and what's not as the way i have been taught is that any woman that he can marry is haram to him.

Comment: Maaf. I am still finding my way around the site. I got married earlier this year to a man who has been divorced now going on 12 years. I would like to know if his ex wife is haram to him in the sense of being alone with him without me being present? I have always dealt with my feelings of uncomfortability because of the children they have together and not wanting to cause hassles but i do not feel comfortable with this set up. I am trying to understand what is acceptable and Whats not as the way i have been taught is that amy woman that he can marry is haram to him.

Comment: I've changed/edited your post according to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

No, he can't be with her alone unless some other person mahram to her is present - like a brother or her kids. If their kids are present, then there is no need for you to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add the following: Are among these children male children (maybe the age?).

Basically after divorce husband and wife are foreigners (non-mahrams) and shouldn't be alone in a room. In presence of a male "mahram" (for example a son of the woman) they might be allowed to meet or in some circumstances they might meet in public.

But what you've learnt is correct. Of course in case of a third divorce they still will be non-mahrams, but can't get married unless the ex wife has married and divorced an other man ...

Usually it is the best -and the closest to what the shari'a allow- if the contact between both doesn't go further than necessary (greeting, exchanging information/news about their children).

Comment: By 'foreigners' do you mean  'strangers' ? But if I understand correctly even a family member can be a non-mahram not just strangers.

Comment: @Ahmed gharib in Arabic: means foreigner or stranger and is used to refer to non-mahrams. Yes family members can be strangers like the sister in law (for a male) or the brother in law (for a female).